# Uppercase after symbol or character with PHP

Tags: php, character, uppercase, lowercase

well I'm having a problem when I try to uppercase the first letter after a symbol or character and actually works great but if my string have spaces between words the code ignore de uppercase and print as is, for example:

```
$string = "&#149;TEXT";

$string = ucfirst(strtolower($string));

$string = preg_replace_callback('/[.!?].*?\w/', create_function('$matches', 'return strtoupper($matches[0]);'),$string);

$string = preg_replace('/^&#149;([a-z])([a-z]+)$/e', '"&#149;" . strtoupper("\\1") . "\2"', $string);

echo $string; //This print •Text
```

The above example shows the text correctly but this does not have spaces. If have space like the next code it shows all the text in lowercase, example:

```
$string = "&#149;TEXT EXAMPLE";

$string = ucfirst(strtolower($string));

$string = preg_replace_callback('/[.!?].*?\w/', create_function('$matches', 'return strtoupper($matches[0]);'),$string);

$string = preg_replace('/^&#149;([a-z])([a-z]+)$/e', '"&#149;" . strtoupper("\\1") . "\2"', $string);

echo $string; //This print •text example (This is my problem, all is lowercased)
```

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

How about a simpler solution:

```
$str = '&#149;TEXT EXAMPLE';
if (preg_match('/(^&[^;]+;)(.*)/', $str, $matches)) {
    list($discard, $entity, $text) = $matches;
    // list(, $entity, $text) = $matches; // this works too
    $string = $entity . trim(ucfirst(strtolower($text)));
    echo $string;
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: Works great but when I try to use it with my script it stop working, I sure i'm doing something wrong but I don't know where is the problem.

I take the text from a XML feed @Twisted1919

`$str = eregi_replace(".*<ficha_comercial>","",$part[$i]);
if (preg_match('/(^&[^;]+;)(.*)/', $str, $matches)) {
    list($discard, $entity, $text) = $matches;
    // list(, $entity, $text) = $matches; // this works too
    $string = $entity . trim(ucfirst(strtolower($text)));
    echo $string;
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}`

Comment: After your `eregi_replace()`, does your `$str` still contains something? You should use `preg_*` instead of `ereg_*`. Also, you should typecast you `$str` in a string: `$str = (string)preg_replace('/[^<]*<ficha_comercial>/ix','',$part[$i]);` (the regex is not tested)